# Comparing size of array in MongoDB subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Given a document like this

```
{
  _id: '1234',
  items: [{
    qty: 2,
    assigned: ['a', 'b']
  }, {
    qty: 3,
    assigned: []
  }]
}
```

I want to match this document because `qty` is greater than `assigned.length`. Can this be done directly with a query?

---

### ** Edit **

I was looking at the `$size` operator, but it only accept a number.

Comment: Like your other question, this is a case for `$where`

Comment: I'm pretty sure some day MongoDB will support this feature... But I guess I have no other choice but to write an ugly `$where` operator, then :/

Comment: Or you can denormalize your model a little bit and add a `qtyExceedsAssigned` boolean key in your `items` array and search directly on that after running a bulk update to set it.

Comment: I already denormalized a lot, since this is a major version upgrade of an app that used to run on postgreSQL. Simply the porting of the data was a challenge, and the amount of fields I added and now maintain is becoming confusing.